# in UTF-8 is there any multi-byte character containing the byte \x27 / chr(39) / ' / single-quote-character?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, quotes

.. as the title says, in UTF-8 is there any multi-byte character containing the byte \x27  / chr(39)  / ' / single-quote-character ?

you may wonder why anyone would want to know that?
well, when trying to bypass the function

```php
function quoteLinuxShellArgument(string $argument): string {
    if(false!==strpos($argument,"\x00")){error it is impossible to quote null bytes in shell arguments}
    return "'" . str_replace ( "'", "'\\''", $argument ) . "'";
}
```

among my first questions was the one in the title.. is there any?

Comment: No, BTW POSIX disallows any encoding with such characteristic, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271: slash and NULL must be fix on all encodings. UTF8 was developed because Unix/POSIX (cf. UTF-1 which was ISO 2022 and C char compatible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), any Unicode codepoint that is outside of the ASCII range (`U+0000` - `U+007F`) is required to be encoded using multiple bytes.  All of those bytes will have their high bit set to 1.

So no, byte `0x27` (`b00100111`) will never appear in a multi-byte sequence. `0x27` can only ever be used to encode codepoint `U+0027 APOSTROPHE` as a single byte.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

All of the multi-byte UTF-8 characters have the upper bit set, so there's no chance of colliding with a regular ASCII character.  That includes your single quote.