# PHP how to convert UTF-8 to MUTF-8?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, mutf-8

in PHP, how can i convert UTF-8 to [MUTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8)? i am hoping i can lazily just get away with

```
function utf8_to_mutf8(string $utf8):string{
    return str_replace("\x00", "\xC0\x80", $utf8);
}
```

? given that [all multi-byte characters in utf-8 have the high bit set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021059/in-utf-8-is-there-any-multi-byte-character-containing-the-byte-x27-chr39/72021151#72021151), \x00 will never occur in any multi-byte character, and the following should be completely unnecessary?

```
function utf8_to_mutf8(string $utf8):string{
    $old = mb_internal_encoding();
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    $ret = mb_ereg_replace("\x00", "\xC0\x80",$utf8);
    mb_internal_encoding($old);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I think you miss the reason of the second function: it can be used also when `mb_internal_encoding` is not UTF-8. You are assuming it. (so it is not about not having extra 00 in text)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi both functions can be used regardless of the mb_internal_encoding setting. the first function does not care about mb_ and the second function makes sure to save the original mb_internal before setting mb_internal to utf-8, doing the conversion, then restoring mb_internal to whatever it was before, then returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, `"\x00"` will only occur for codepoint U+0000 and never for any other codepoint. [Only all ASCII characters have the highest bit not set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) (U+0000 to U+007F = bits 00000000 to 01111111). Encountering bytes that have not the highest bit set can also be used for sychronization in case it is unclear where the next codepoint/character begins.
- Yes, [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) is enough, because it is already [binary safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-safe), as said in the docs. Speak: it does neither care about the input's encoding, nor about global settings.

If your goal is to have a chain of bytes that will never ever have a `"\x00"` in it then you should achieve it this way.

Personally I think [null terminations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string#Limitations) are outdated, and following the old Java way to work around that limitation just comes with the same disadvantages of not being able to use `"\x00"` in the first way. You just end up to unmodify your encoding again to let all UTF-8 handling properly deal with it.